# Averageif with criteria being related to a different cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, worksheet-function

I have an array of numbers in excel, and I want to get the average of all numbers where the column headers matches a pattern.

Currently, I have data that looks like this:

[image: My data]

At the bottom I have an if function that used the column header (if it contains "Yes"), and then sums, and the last cell does an `AVERAGEIF`. Is there a way to get the same result without the extra values at the bottom somehow?

Ideally, I would like to use `COLUMN` and the like in the criteria, and somehow get that as an array that can be used, but I am not sure how to make that work syntactically.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps use `SUMPRODUCT` to get the sum of all the columns with the given restrictions, then `COUNTIF` to get the number of columns with the given restriction:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:D11*ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Yes",A1:D1)))/COUNTIF(A1:D1,"*Yes*")
```

`SUMPRODUCT` should return 77+88 and `COUNTIF` should return 2.

The above formula is case insensitive.

A case sensitive one:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:D11*ISNUMBER(FIND("Yes",A1:D1)))/SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND("Yes",A1:D1)))
```

Comment: This is a pretty clever way of using an error to your advantage. +1 for correctness as well.